# How to calculate the min. and max packet size of a flow

Tags: python, sockets, networking, packet, netflow

I am trying trying to get the minimum, maximum packet size of a flow and also the inter-arrival time between the packets from a network traffic which I captured. I have tried but i did not make any progress.

The code below: 
 1. Counts the number of TCP flows in the pcap file.
 2. Counts the number of UDP flows in the pcap file.
 3. Counts the number of unique IP addresses.
 4. Calculate the total number of packets per flow.
 5. Calculate the average packet size per flow.
 6. Calculate the duration of each flow. Please I will really appreciate your help so much!!

This is the code below

```
import dpkt
from functools import reduce
import socket
import statistics


tflows = {}
uflows = {}
ips = set()

#Counters
counter=0
ipcounter=0
nonipcounter=0    
pktcounter=0
ipv4counter=0
totaltcpcounter=0
totaludpcounter=0

def dumpFlow(flows, flow):
    print(f'Data for flow: {flow}:')
    bytes = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y,
                   map(lambda e: e['byte_count'], flows[flow]))
    packets = reduce(lambda a, z: a+z,
                    map(lambda e: e['packet_count'], flows[flow]))
    Flow_protocol = sorted(map(lambda e: e['protocol'], flows[flow]))
    Flow_protocol = (Flow_protocol[0])
    duration = sorted(map(lambda e: e['ts'], flows[flow]))
    duration = duration[-1] - duration[0]
    print(f"\tTotal Bytes: {bytes}")
    print(f"\tTotal Number of Packets per flow: {packets}")
    print(f"\tAverage Bytes: {bytes / len(flows[flow])}")
    print(f"\tTotal Duration: {duration}")
    print(f"\tMean Packets: {packets / 2}")
    print(f"\tFlow Protocol: {Flow_protocol}")

# Packet processing loop
for ts,pkt in dpkt.pcap.Reader(open('tesst.pcap','rb')):
    pktcounter = 0
    counter+=1

    eth=dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(pkt)


     #check if IP packet or non-ip packet
    if eth.type == dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP:
            ipcounter = ipcounter + 1
    else:
            nonipcounter = nonipcounter + 1 

    if eth.type==dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP:
        ipv4counter+=1
        ip=eth.data

        # determine transport layer type
        if ip.p==dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_TCP:
            pktcounter+=1
            totaltcpcounter+=1
            flows = tflows
        elif ip.p==dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_UDP:
            pktcounter+=1
            totaludpcounter+=1
            flows = uflows           

        # extract IP and transport layer data
        src_ip = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.src)
        src_port = ip.data.sport
        dst_ip = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.dst)
        dst_port = ip.data.dport


        # keeping set of unique IPs
        ips.add(src_ip)
        ips.add(dst_ip)

        # store flow data
        flow = sorted([(src_ip, src_port), (dst_ip, dst_port)])
        #print(flow)
        flow = (flow[0], flow[1])
        flow_data = {
            'byte_count': len(eth),
            'packet_count': (pktcounter),
            'ts': ts,
            'protocol': ip.p
           }


        if flows.get(flow):
            flows[flow].append(flow_data)
        else:
            flows[flow] = [flow_data]


print ("Total number of ETHERNET packets in the PCAP file :", counter)
print ("\t\tTotal number of IP packets :", ipcounter)
print ("\t\tTotal number of TCP packets :", totaltcpcounter)

print ("\t\tTotal number of UDP packets :", totaludpcounter)    
print ("\t\tTotal number of IPV4 packets :", ipv4counter)
print ("\t\tTotal number of NON-IP packets :", nonipcounter)
print ("----------------------------------------------------------------------")


print(f'Total number of TCP flows: {len(tflows.keys())}')
print(f'Total number of UDP flows: {len(uflows.keys())}')
print(f'Total number of unique IPs: {len(ips)}')

for k in tflows.keys():
    dumpFlow(tflows, k)
for k in uflows.keys():
    dumpFlow(uflows, k)
```

Comment: How do you think you should get the min/max packet size and inter-packet size of flow?

Comment: @RossJacobs, the min/max packet size will be gotten from the tuple. for example, the packets from src to destination and from the same destination to the same src in a flow (src_IP, src_port, dst_IP, dst_port). while the inter-arrival time between the packets should be the time between the first packet and the second packet....packet N. I am open to correction if my answer is not correct. Thanks

Comment: @wobr how are you doing? please, were you able to look at it?